# The code is creating i.e. local variable 'p' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, local

i wrote a function including while statement in python(2) . This is creating an error stated below. Please help me to olve this error. Thanks in advance.

**Error**

```
the numbers'll increase in order of 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex28.py", line 27, in <module>
    numgame(100, 2)
  File "ex28.py", line 20, in numgame
    while p < i:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'p' referenced before assignment
```

**Original Code**

```
numbers = []
def numgame(i, inc):
    print "the numbers'll increase in order of %r" % inc
    while p < i:
        print "At top is %d" % p
        numbers.append(p)
        print "The list is %r" % numbers
        p += inc
        print "The next number to be added to the list is %d" % p

numgame(100, 2)
```

Comment: Error is quite clear, you didn't define a `p` before using it in while condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `p` with some value before you can compare it `p < i`:

```
numbers = []
def numgame(i, inc):
    print "the numbers'll increase in order of %r" % inc
    p = 0                           # initialize p
    while p < i:
        print "At top is %d" % p
        numbers.append(p)
        print "The list is %r" % numbers
        p += inc
        print "The next number to be added to the list is %d" % p

numgame(100, 2)
```

Comment: it is still creating that error

Comment: Have you hit "save" before running the file?

Comment: yes i hit the save. My problem is solved i was declaring the variable outside the function